# What is a Useful Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Useful Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Useful Words™ | Not Useful Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ALL | ANY |
| NEAR | AT |
| BORROW | BEG |
| CURSE | BLESS |
| SNITCH | BLUDGER |
| CANER | CANNER |
| REBS | DEBS |
| LIGHTEST | GRAVEST |
| SUPPED | LUNCHED |
| DIAMOND | MOD |
| AND | NOR |
| COVERT | OVERT |
| QUAYS | PIERS |
| GREEN | RED |
| OTHERS | SELF |
| GAMBLE | WAGER |
| BLACKEST | WHITEST |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Useful Words™,Not Useful Words™
ALL,ANY
NEAR,AT
BORROW,BEG
CURSE,BLESS
SNITCH,BLUDGER
CANER,CANNER
REBS,DEBS
LIGHTEST,GRAVEST
SUPPED,LUNCHED
DIAMOND,MOD
AND,NOR
COVERT,OVERT
QUAYS,PIERS
GREEN,RED
OTHERS,SELF
GAMBLE,WAGER
BLACKEST,WHITEST
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Useful Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Useful Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

**—HINTS—**

*helpfulness level 0:*

> The name fits here, technically; a different name might have been more appropriate.

*helpfulness level 1:*

> There are *way* more Useful Words™ than Not Useful Words™.

*helpfulness level 2:*

> This is likely impossible to solve unless you start with the right words.

Comment: _My_ "brain" _is not a useful word for determining the solution to this puzzle._

Comment: Perhaps a helpfulness Level 7 hint? :p

Comment: Does this, perchance, have something to do with the age or relevance of the words?

Comment: @nine9 I don’t know the age of any of these words. I don’t know what you mean by relevance (to what?)

Comment: Something I find interesting is that the Not Useful™ words are all in alphabetical order, unlike Useful™ words; that might (or might not) mean they are found by filtering a dictionary automatically. The list also ends at the letter W that is fairly close to the end of the alphabet, so these might even (or might not) be the only Not Useful™ words.

Comment: @someone There are many more Useful Words™ and Not Useful Words™ than those listed above. (As for the order, it's typical and indeed [recommended](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5814) to apply some ordering in these puzzles, and I use alphabetical order more often than not; make of that what you will.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A Not Useful Word™ is a word that...

> ...can have "one" added somewhere within it to make a new word:
>
>   ANY => ANY**ONE**
>   AT => AT**ONE**
>   BEG => BEG**ONE**
>   BLESS => B**ONE**LESS
>   BLUDGER => BLUDGE**ONE**R
>   CANNER => CANN**ONE**ER
>   DEBS => DEB**ONE**S
>   GRAVEST => GRAVEST**ONE**
>   LUNCHED => LUNCHE**ONE**D
>   MOD => MO**ONE**D
>   NOR => NO**ONE**R
>   OVERT => OVERT**ONE**
>   PIERS => PI**ONE**ERS
>   RED => RED**ONE**
>   SELF => **ONE**SELF
>   WAGER => WAG**ONE**ER
>   WHITEST => WHITEST**ONE**

As for the name Useful Word™...

> ...Rand al'Thor figured that out [in a comment below](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83981/what-is-a-useful-word/84202?noredirect=1#comment244554_84202):
>
>  The idea behind the name seems to be based on the **downvote tooltip on Stack Exchange**. You give *minus one* for an answer that's *not useful*, hence "not useful" for a word which, when ONE is 'subtracted', is still meaningful.

Comment: -1 "This answer is not useful" ;)

Comment: @gnovice (I've just given you a rather gigantic hint)

Comment: @gnovice The idea behind the name seems to be based on the **downvote tooltip on Stack Exchange**. You give *minus one* for an answer that's *not useful*, hence "not useful" for a word which, when ONE is 'subtracted', is still meaningful.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Ahhh, totally missed the hint. That's surely the answer.

Comment: Oooh, clever. I'll go ahead and award the bounty.