# What is an Even Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an ***Even Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Even Words™ | Not Even Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ABATING | GROWING |
| PORK | BACON |
| EGGED | PAPERED |
| BLESSED | DEFILED |
| UNCOPYRIGHTABLE | COPYRIGHTABLE |
| INQUISITION | UNEXPECTED |
| ZEBRA | HORSE |
| CAT | FOX |
| SOOTHED | INFLAMMATION |
| PERPLEXES | ENLIGHTENS |
| TRADEMARKED | DISOWNED |
| ENCRYPTED | ENCIPHERED |
| QUICKLY | SLUGGISHLY |
| DISCUSSION | ARGUMENT |
| PUPPY | KITTY |
| CUTEST | UGLIEST |
| EXCELLENT | INSUFFICIENT |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Even Words™,Not Even Words™
ABATING,GROWING
PORK,BACON
EGGED,PAPERED
BLESSED,DEFILED
UNCOPYRIGHTABLE,COPYRIGHTABLE
INQUISITION,UNEXPECTED
ZEBRA,HORSE
CAT,FOX
SOOTHED,INFLAMMATION
PERPLEXES,ENLIGHTENS
TRADEMARKED,DISOWNED
ENCRYPTED,ENCIPHERED
QUICKLY,SLUGGISHLY
DISCUSSION,ARGUMENT
PUPPY,KITTY
CUTEST,UGLIEST
EXCELLENT,INSUFFICIENT
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is an Even Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Even Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Oh, and Not Even Words™ are actually words. They are not to be confused with words that are "not even words".

Seeing as this is my first puzzle here, feel free to offer feedback! I worked hard to make it look and work as nice as possible, and I have some hints prepared if they become necessary.

Happy Puzzling!

EDIT: Seeing as the puzzle has been solved, if anyone would like to see the information related to the solution, it can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/rS7CDFA5)

Comment: I used https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83981/what-is-a-useful-word to get the chart formatting and general template, so some of the wording is the same/similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think an Even Word is

> a word that by taking A=1, B=2,...,Z=26 and summing the values of the letters of the words yields an even number.

Comment: ..Well, that was fast. Took me QUITE a lot longer to make this than it took you to solve it! Will give you the check when it lets me.